# Turning if and Else Statement into something I can echo?

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

Basically, the below that is the php I currently have and works and does the 'conversion' perfect, but I do want to put it inside a string that's already working.

```
    $level0 = 0;
    $level1 = 24999;
    $level2 = 49999;
    $level3 = 74999;
    $level4 = 99999;
    $level5 = 124999;

    if ($myallcreadits < $level0) { 
        echo('LEVEL0'); }
    if ($myallcreadits < $level1) { 
        echo('LEVEL1'); }
    if ($myallcreadits < $level2) { 
        echo('LEVEL2'); }
    if ($myallcreadits < $level3) { 
        echo('LEVEL3'); }
    if ($myallcreadits < $level4) { 
        echo('LEVEL4'); }
    if ($myallcreadits < $level5) { 
        echo('LEVEL5'); }
```

i.e My example would be to achieve the below example further down the page:

```
$details='<div id="level">'.$level.'</div>'
```

And I would like it to echo out the Current level it is depending if it's lower or equal to in a different place, as I don't want to echo the current levels where they currently are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this

```
<?php

$level0 = 0;
$level1 = 24999;
$level2 = 49999;
$level3 = 74999;
$level4 = 99999;
$level5 = 124999;

$myallcreadits = 24543;


if ($myallcreadits < $level0) {
    $level='LEVEL0'; }
elseif ($myallcreadits < $level1) {
    $level='LEVEL1'; }
elseif ($myallcreadits < $level2) {
    $level='LEVEL2'; }
elseif ($myallcreadits < $level3) {
    $level='LEVEL3'; }
elseif ($myallcreadits < $level4) {
    $level='LEVEL4'; }
elseif ($myallcreadits < $level5) {
    $level='LEVEL5'; }

echo $details='<div id="level">'.$level.'</div>'; //Prints LEVEL1
```

Comment: I doubt. It has same mistake as OP's logic: it will always result in `LECEL5` for small values of `$myallcreadits`

Comment: @AlmaDo, That is correct. `elseif` should fix the issue right ?

Comment: Yes, it will fix. But it's weird

Comment: This will solve the issue, but I think this should be a function instead. +1 regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Really, why do such thing? Your logic has mistake: you'll overwrite your old values with new since if `$myallcreadits < 49999` then it's obviously, also `< 124999`. Also, use arrays - what if you'll have 50 levels?

```
$levels = [
  'LEVEL0'=>0, 
  'LEVEL1'=>24999, 
  'LEVEL2'=>49999, 
  'LEVEL3'=>74999, 
  'LEVEL4'=>99999, 
  'LEVEL5'=>124999
];
//$myallcreadits=50000;
$filter = array_filter($levels, function($x) use ($myallcreadits)
{
   return $x<$myallcreadits;
});
end($filter);
$result = key($filter);
$details='<div id="$result">'.$result.'</div>';
```

*Update*:

If you want your levels with step 25000 (minus 1, obviously), use:

```
$values = array_map(function($x)
{
   return $x-1;
}, range(0, 125000, 25000));
$values[0] = 0;
$keys   = array_map(function($x)
{
   return 'LEVEL'.$x;
}, range(0, count($values)-1));
$levels = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Comment: Well is there a way to make every 25,000 it goes up, that it goes up another Level?

Comment: ? I'm guessing the max is 125k?

Comment: @user1077369 it's a sample. You can use it and define your own limit

Answer (score 0):

Better to use some dynamic levels values.

```
$levels = array(1 => 0, 24999, 49999, 74999, 99999, 124999);

$myallcreadits = 60000;
$current_level = 0;
foreach($levels as $index => $level)
  {
  if ($myallcreadits > $level)
    $current_level = $index;
  }

echo $current_level;
```

Comment: This works, but the levels are slightly messed up, the current level it is spits out for 60000 is 2. When it should be level 3.

Comment: Brilliant! I did try an array but couldn't grasp it that well! But I do kind of understand as I got to this around the same time you did! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

So what you seem to be trying to achieve is to put your credits into a number of levels.

```
$level = ceil( ($credits + 1) / 25000);

if ($level < 0) $level = 0;
if ($level > 5) $level = 5;

$leveltext = 'LEVEL' + $level;

echo $leveltext;
```

However, I think you should try to run your code because it will print out: LEVEL1LEVEL2LEVEL3LEVEL4LEVEL5